# What's the best way for using ReactJs with Cordova?

Tags: cordova, reactjs, hybrid-mobile-app

I love using react but react-native have fewer plugins than Cordova so I was wondering how to use it with material-ui and Cordova

how to connect both with webpack, and how to use Cordova plugins inside the react code?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

In `webpack.config.js` put the `index.html` and output the build file in `www` folder.
Cordova will take the single page app from `www` folder

Comment: What I personally don't understand is this statement: `Cordova will take the single page app from www folder`. Can you please explain a bit more.

Comment: configure your webpack, so it can generate the output files in www folder.
and in cordova config make the entry file as index.html of www folder.